# Position footer to bottom of window or page, whichever is larger

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a site that requires a footer to be placed either at the bottom of the window, or the bottom of the page content, whichever is lower. I have tried using the `height: 100%` method, but this causes a problem.

I also have a `position: fixed` header, and some padding on my content (defined in pixels). Also, the height of the content may change after the page has loaded (use of accordions, etc.), so I wonder if there's a pure CSS way to position the footer to either the bottom of the window, or the bottom of the document, while still allowing pixel padding and so forth.

Here's an outlined structure of the HTML:

```
<header></header>
<div class="content">
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

I have also put together a Fiddle to demonstrate how the CSS works at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/LY6Zs/. I am unfortunately unable to change the HTML structure (i.e. breaking out the `footer` element from `.content`.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure this is possible, every solution I have seen with a fixed footer has the footer outside the content. There might be a way (I am sure there is) with jQuery or pure js but you said you wanted pure CSS. Is there a particular reason you can't change the HTML? The change itself to make a sticky footer is pretty inconsequential and really shouldn't break any properly laid out page.

Comment: There's no real reason that I can't change the markup, other than that the previous devs who created the site seem to have assigned jQuery selectors and CSS styles as `.content footer`, which means there are several thousand lines of code to work through in order to make sure no selector is forgotten!

Comment: ugh >.< one of the reasons I am NOT a huge fan of setting selectors like that. Honestly in your case there is no reason I can see for that, is there another footer somewhere else? (yeah didn't think so). Quite honestly I'd probably change that anyway just to clean up the CSS and make the selectors make more sense.

Comment: Damn, looks like I'm SOL then!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You first need to have a container div just after the  which contains all the content

```
.container
{
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
}

.footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```